# Convert txt file to arff file via TextDirectoryToArff.java

Tags: java, weka, arff

I am trying to convert txt file to arff via `TextDirectoryToArff.java`. I am using eclipse on Windows OS, and the usage tells me to `TextDirectoryToArff <directory path>`. But I am not sure what it means.
Could somebody help me with this program?

**TextDirectoryToArff.java :-**

```
import java.io.*;
import weka.core.*;

/**
 * Builds an arff dataset from the documents in a given directory.
 * Assumes that the file names for the documents end with ".txt".
 *
 * Usage:<p>
 *
 * TextDirectoryToArff <directory path><p>
 *
 * @author Richard Kirkby (rkirkby at cs.waikato.ac.nz)
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class TextDirectoryToArff {

  public Instances createDataset(String directoryPath) throws Exception {

    FastVector atts = new FastVector(2);
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("filename", (FastVector) null));
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("contents", (FastVector) null));
    Instances data = new Instances("text_files_in_" + directoryPath, atts, 0);

    File dir = new File(directoryPath);
    String[] files = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (files[i].endsWith(".txt")) {
    try {
      double[] newInst = new double[2];
      newInst[0] = (double)data.attribute(0).addStringValue(files[i]);
      File txt = new File(directoryPath + File.separator + files[i]);  
      InputStreamReader is;
      is = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(txt));
      StringBuffer txtStr = new StringBuffer();
      int c;
      while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
        txtStr.append((char)c);
      }
      newInst[1] = (double)data.attribute(1).addStringValue(txtStr.toString());
      data.add(new Instance(1.0, newInst));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //System.err.println("failed to convert file: " + directoryPath + File.separator + files[i]);
    }
      }
    }
    return data;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length == 1) {
      TextDirectoryToArff tdta = new TextDirectoryToArff();
      try {
          Instances dataset = tdta.createDataset(args[0]);
          System.out.println(dataset);
          } 
      catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }

    else {
      System.out.println("Usage: java TextDirectoryToArff <directory name>");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Fixed structure of the question. Provided description of the question in start and the code in the end. Removed unnecessary license information from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Weka is asking you to use JAVA to execute TextDirectoryToArff  passing as a parameter the directory.

You have two options:

- 1) Generate a JAR called "TextDirectoryToArff" and then use JAVA though the console in Windows and execute java TextDirectoryToArff passign a directory as a paratemer.
- 2) From Eclipse you can pass your directory directly like, modifying the dataset and then doing Run, run

  ```
   Instances dataset = tdta.createDataset(args[0]);
  ```

  To:

  ```
   Instances dataset = tdta.createDataset("C:\\yourDir");
  ```